# Java: waiting on synchronized block, who goes first?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, scheduling

This question is inspired by [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940112/multi-threading).

If multiple threads are waiting on a `synchronized` block, and the lock becomes available, who goes first? Is it by thread priority (and then first-come-first-served)?

And do the same rules apply for `notify` (with multiple `wait`ing threads)?

Comment: If 'fair locks' are what you are looking for, then look at the java.util.concurrent package. As an example, ReEntrantLocks are fair. The fairness comes from the fact that priority is given to longest waiting threads, analogous to 'Aging' concept in process scheduling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this guy: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/starvation-and-fairness.html

Java issues no guarantees about the sequence. So I guess it is not based on thread priority

I'll try to look further for an explanation on how Java actually decides who goes first.

Comment: +1 Interesting.  Turns out that the locks in the concurrency package have an optional fairness mode, in which case they work fifo. If not, it is arbitrary. I would have thought that thread priority should play a role here.

Comment: I agree that would have been the "natural" choice.

Comment: Fairness comes at a cost, and the predictability is achieved at the expense of big throughput drop. Also, the fairness requirement would prevent tons of optimizations that VM might do in implementing lock acquisitions (things like thin spin-locks, etc.).

Comment: One question abouth this: if thread1 is the holder of the monitor and other threads are waiting, is it possible for thread1 to unlock and race "around" and get the lock again before ANY of the already waiting threads?

Comment: @dmansfield I can't give any definitive answer, but it SEEMS like that's what's happening in my code.  If anybody has a more official answer, I'd like to hear it.

Answer (score 6):

Someone else mentioned the availability of fair locks.  If you really care who goes first, then you may have a real-time problem.  In that case, you can make use of RTSJ, wherein the ordering and other semantics of lock acquisition is specified.  The specifics are available in the [RTSJ Spec](http://www.rtsj.org/specjavadoc/book_index.html) under *Synchronization*.  Quoting from the rationale section:

> Java's rules for synchronized code
>   provide a means for mutual exclusion
>   but do not prevent unbounded priority
>   inversions and thus are insufficient
>   for real-time applications. This
>   specification strengthens the
>   semantics for synchronized code by
>   mandating priority inversion control,
>   in particular by furnishing classes
>   for priority inheritance and priority
>   ceiling emulation. Priority
>   inheritance is more widely implemented
>   in real-time operating systems and
>   thus is required and is the initial
>   default mechanism in this
>   specification.

Answer (score 1):

for your second Question

> one of them is chosen to be awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of   the implementation. A thread waits on an object's monitor by calling one of the wait methods.

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()

Comment: Any idea how Hotspot handles this?

Comment: If I take these two answer together with Thread priorities not resulting in OS thread priorities on Linux (at least in most situations), those priorities don't seem to do a lot...

Comment: @Thilo It depends on implementation. I Can't say that is OS dependent.

Comment: @Thilo, are you planning to write code depending on the behaviour?

Comment: I actually believe it's OS dependent too since besides a small amount of spinlocking (perhaps 10000 attempts or 10us of attempts) it will leave the OS actually handle it further.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on thread priority and thread scheduling algorithm and also the lock on the synchronized block is not "fair". This means that if there are 2 waiting threads with the same priority and the first thread waited more than the second thread that doesn't necessarily mean that the first thread will be executed first.

Comment: Are you saying that higher priority does go first?

Comment: no sorry I'm not saying that, I missed that case. I'm saying that even a thread with higher priority could be executed after a thread with lower priority because of the fairness. This is because unfair lock provide weaker liveness guarantees that require that all threads will eventually acquire the lock.

Comment: The lock is unfair and the only way that higher priority threads are more likely to successfully acquire the lock than lower priority ones is that the lower priority threads are starved of execution time itself.