# Which thread will get the lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

suppose we have multi processor machine and multi threaded application. If two threads have access to a synchronized method and they got executed at the same time which thread will gets the lock?
or what will happen?

Thanks

Comment: I guess, VM will have to toss a coin.

Comment: Somewhat related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940164/java-waiting-on-synchronized-block-who-goes-first

Comment: Does that mean the VM is allowed to starve one thread if both threads try to acquire the lock in a loop?

Comment: @Peter G, yes, see my answer.

Comment: @Peter G: per spec it could. But a clever implementation will have some ways around it (such as approximate arrival order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that there is no such thing as "at the same time". One of the two will get the lock, but you have no way to know which one.

There is no such thing "at at the same time" because, liberally speaking, a lock is *something* that chooses and executes the threads one at a time exclusively.

This is naturally accomplished in a pure monoprocessor system that can execute one instruction at a time. On multiprocessor systems usually there is some hardware device that "locks" the processors to prevent them from executing at the same time.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be something as "at the same time". We're talking about a multi-processor hardware...

Comment: But the code that is managing the lock must be serializing somehow.

Comment: @Feras, aioobe: Even in a multi-processor system, there are operations that can not execute concurrently (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_(computer_science)#Primitive_atomic_instructions ) and any implementation of sychrnonized must necessarily use such operations to ensure that no two threads enter the lock at the same time.

Comment: Yes, sure, that's the point of a lock. I (and I suspect the Feras as well) was asking about the case in which two threads *asks* for the lock at the same time. This must surely be possible...

Comment: ... but part of asking for that lock is executing the atomic instruction, and that part can't execute "at the same time".

Answer (score 9):

The behaviour will be **non-deterministic** (that is, either thread may get the lock), and it may vary from execution to execution. This is because it depends on the specific JVM implementation, and the particular scheduling of your threads.

According to this article the JVM specification puts no restrictions on fairness:

> ***Fairness***
>   *The Java memory model does not specify any fairness requirement for threads or preemptive multi-threading. A thread can refuse to surrender the CPU to another thread and throw the system into deadlock. The rules for fairness to other threads are defined by the individual JVM implementations.*

That is, unless you carefully synchronize your program, one thread may theoretically get starved by the scheduler.

Comment: I also don't think that there will be any "at the same time" at that level. One thread will get the lock, just by virtue of getting there first. No need for a coin toss.